# How can I tell if a module (dropdown, checkbox, etc.) is already bound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

In Semantic UI, how can I tell if, say, a give `.ui.dropdown` has already been initialized as a dropdown (using `$(.ui.dropdown).dropdown(...)`)?

I'm asking because I want to define a 'fallback' that will initialize any uninitialized dropdowns (or checkboxes, or other JavaScript-bound modules) with default parameters. However, initializing them twice often yields strange behaviour.

Example:

```
$('.ui.dropdown.special').dropdown({ action: somethingSpecial() });

// Later...

$('.ui.dropdown').each(function()
{
    if (/* $(this) is not already a dropdown */)
    {
        $(this).dropdown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I've found so far is to manually add an attribute and check for it:

```
$.fn.safeDropdown = function(args)
{
    $dropdown = $(this);

    if (!$dropdown.is('[data-semantic]'))
    {
        $dropdown.attr('data-semantic', 'dropdown');
        $dropdown.dropdown(args);
    }
};
```

But this is less than ideal because it requires changing all the existing code and because it's longer to type.

Comment: There is a hidden data variable with the format `module-<namespace>` attached to the element, we can use that to check if the elements are initialized. For example: `$(elem).data('module-dropdown')`